# mysterious missing letters in print of Word document

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

I have a HP Laser Print which print other document (pdf etc) just fine. However, with a word document, the print (and preview) have missing print letters. See screenshot. I have tried to reset printer, make sure the driver PCL4/5 etc, no avail. Any idea?

[image]

Comment: If the preview is missing the letters then it is not the printer that is the issue. What program are you printing it from? If you save it as a text file and open it in Notepad do you have the same issue. If you change the font do you have the same issue?

Comment: How it looks like exported to pdf?

Comment: Ah... yeah I missed that... ha.... Well at least reboot the machine if you haven't already though. Troubleshooting 101 in case the memory is fragmented this will clear it out and give it a fresh start; electricity and fragmented memory can cause strange issues sometimes..... Also, what version of MS Word is this and on what OS or you running it on?